# Hibernate Implementation with JPA2.0

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, crud

I have a question regarding JPA. We are using Hibernate for JPA 2.0 and whenever we want to perform some CRUD operations we will import API for JPA but not Hibernate.But the methods are just interfaces in the JPA since JPA is just a specification and not the implementation.So how does the CRUD operations work when we have entityManager.createQuery() sort of calls which are just the abstract methods and not the concrete methods. Little bit confused... Responses appreciated.

Comment: I think both answers are addressing your question, so please pick one.

Answer (score 0):

The EntityManager is an interface and each JPA provider offers an implementation for it. The Hibernate EntityManager implementation simply delegates all calls to the current running Session.

The CRUD operations are backed by EntityManager methods:

- persist
- merge
- remove
- createQuery

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to understand what is the difference between JPA and Hibernate but also difference between SessionFactory and EntityManager (both are available in framework called "JPA/Hibernate"). Long story short.. the entityManager is the implementation of the standard, by standard I mean JPA, in sessionFactory there is lots of features from Hibernate (and it is **no** standard).

The recommended one is EntityManager because it is a standard. For more information http://www.javabeat.net/jpa-entitymanager-vs-hibernate-sessionfactory/